# scala mongodb document getList

Tags: mongodb, scala, mongo-scala-driver

I would like to get **groups** attribute as Seq[Int] from the given mongodb Document. How to do it? The method **getList** catches a runtime exception, and I would like to understand and fix it.

```
 n: Document((_id,BsonObjectId{value=613645d689898b7d4ac2b1b2}), (groups,BsonArray{values=[BsonInt32{value=2}, BsonInt32{value=3}]}))
```

I tried this way that compiles, but I get the runtime error "**Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: List element cannot be cast to scala.Int$**"

```
  val groups = n.getList("groups", Int.getClass)
```

Some sbt library dependencies:

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.14"
libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb.scala" %% "mongo-scala-driver" % "4.3.1"
```

Setup code:

```
val collection = db.getCollection("mylist")
Await.result(collection.drop.toFuture, Duration.Inf)
val groupsIn = Seq[Int](2, 3)
val doc = Document("groups" -> groupsIn)
Await.result(collection.insertOne(doc).toFuture, Duration.Inf)
println("see mongosh to verify that a Seq[Int] has been added")
val result = Await.result(collection.find.toFuture, Duration.Inf)
for(n <- result) {
  println("n: " + n)
  val groups = n.getList("groups", Int.getClass)
  println("groups: " + groups)
}
```

Comments: **result** is of type Seq[Document], n is of type Document.

The getList hover-on description in VSCODE:

```
def getList[T](key: Any, clazz: Class[T]): java.util.List[T]
Gets the list value of the given key, casting the list elements to the given Class. This is useful to avoid having casts in client code, though the effect is the same.
```

Comment: Can you give a bit more context: which libray do you use, what version?

Comment: I have updated the post.

Comment: And what is the type of `n`, I don't see any `getList` method in the API docs

Comment: I have updated the post with your comments.

Comment: `val groups = n.getList("groups", classOf[Integer])`

Comment: sarveshseri, your comment is a big advance in the solution. What is left to do is to convert to Seq[Int] in the efficient way and this can be considered a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of **sarveshseri** and **Gael J**, the solution is reached:

```
import collection.JavaConverters._

val groups = n.getList("groups", classOf[Integer]).asScala.toSeq.map(p => p.toInt)
```